# List comprehension variable not defined? (Python)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of dicts sortd, i want to add the first three dicts in the list to a new list.

I tried using a list comp for the first time but when doing:

```
new_dict = [pair for pair[0:3] in sortd]
```

i get the error "pair is not defined", what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `new_dict = [pair[0:3] for pair in sortd]` should be closer to what you want

Comment: Note that the `new_dict` won’t be a dict though.

Comment: Just `sortd[:3]` gives the first 3 dicts in the list. No need for a comprehension.

Comment: thanks guys sortd[:3] worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do `pair[:3]` to get the first three elements from `list`. List comprehension is not needed in this case.

List comprehension is alternate and cleaner way to iterate over the list (or dict/tuple) and perform some action. For example, lets say you are having a loop in your code  that creates new list with the square of element in the list as:

```
square_list = []
original_list = [1, ,2 ,3 ,4]
for item in original_list:
    square_list.append(item*item)
```

Equivalent list comprehension implementation will be as:

```
square_list = [item*item for item in original_list]
```

There is a great blog [Python List Comprehensions: Explained Visually](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) explaining the concepts of list comprehension. You might find it useful.

Comment: `item*item for item in ...`